# Restoring the Ubuntu desktop and access to files

Tags: dell, 8.04

I recently got in way over my head playing with Ubuntu 8.04 on a Dell Mini 910.  I think I deleted far more things than I should have trying to "make space".  I started finding the applications I wanted by searching the main files.  Then I selected "change desktop" and really messed things up.  Now when the computer boots up I only see the desktop background with nothing else, no icons, no keys do anything.  I've downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and run it from a thumb-drive on the machine but the hard-drive is too small to load it.  Any clues how I can get access to files, applications?

Thanks.  And if I gave you a laugh, no worries.

john

Answer (score 1):

Given your situation i would consider a fresh install because 
8.04, 8.10, 9.04, and 9.10 have reached there EOL end-of-life, which means they no longer receive support or updates. However, they have been archived and are available:

old releases

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/8.10/

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/8.04.0/

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/9.04/

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/9.10/

Given those options you may also want to consider Lubuntu because it is a lighter-less bloated distribution.

It can be found here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu